# How would the transaction chains created Ark pool transactions work given current mempool policy?

Tags: mempool, ark

If I understood [Ark](https://www.arkpill.me/) correctly, pool transactions (which are on-chain transactions) are connected, as the output of pool transaction `A` is used as an input of the pool transaction `A+1`.

If so, how can that work if there's this mempool policy that limits the number of ascendants/descendants on unconfirmed transactions to 25?

With pool transactions every 5 seconds that would amount to chains of 120 (on average) unconfirmed transactions in the mempool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pool transactions don't need to reference each other.

Suppose, you have a vtxo that was created in round `n` and you want to spend it in round `n+1`.

The idea is that you do some kind of an atomic swap.
You will forfeit your vtxo of round `n` against a new vtxo in round `n+1`.

This is done, by creating two transactions.

- **Forfeiture transaction**: The forfeiture transaction takes a connector from round n+1 as an input. This ensures that the forfeiture transaction is only valid if round `n+1`-occurs exactly as you would expect
- **New vtxo** The new vtxo will also appear in round n+1

We don't need any on-chain link here between pool-transaction `n` and `n+1`.
All the funds entering pool-transaction `n+1` are provided by the ASP.

Comment: And the forfeiture transaction is never broadcasted, is that it?

Comment: Yes, Ark is an optimistic protocol. If everything goes right only the pool transactions will be broadcast.

The LSP only needs to broadcast the forfeiture transaction if someone tries to redeem a forfeited `vtxo`. We don't expect this to happen often. Broadcasting a forfeited `vtxo` is stupid because you pay transaction costs for money you cannot get.